# Is there a structured definition of the Coinbase API?

Tags: api, coinbase-api

Swagger? JSON? YAML? XML?

I'm writing a wrapper library for the Coinbase API, and a formal definition of the endpoints would be incredibly helpful. Is there a parsable definition of the available resources/methods/parameters?